# while loop never ends (python)

Tags: python, while-loop

Have tried to create a check that the generated private key is of even length, but the program gets stuck in this while-loop?

```
    private_key_hex = '{:x}'.format(private_key_dec)
    print ("Length of private_key_hex: ", len(str(private_key_hex)))  

    while (len(private_key_hex) % 2) != 0:  
       private_key_hex = '{:x}'.format(private_key_dec)

    print("Private key (Hex):        " + private_key_hex)  # this never happens...
```

Comment: If it's of odd length, you keep recreating it with the exact same value, so how to you expect it to change and exit the loop?

Comment: You repeatedly create the same hex string from an unchanging decimal value, so yes, that look is going to be endless. The `len(private_key_hex) % 2)` test outcom will **never change** because the inputs never change.

Comment: Thank you, both! I must be in need of some strong coffee! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without knowing the source of `private_key_dec`, I can see you're looping through a string and since you're not changing the value of `private_key_dec`, you're actually reassigning `private_key_hex` to the same value everytime. 
So, if it enters the while loop, it never leaves.

One solutions would be to assign your `private_key_dec` to a list, an instead of the `while` loop, use a `for` loop to this list.
But in order to be more accurate on this, please detail the format in which you receive the data.